# Where can I find the Azure App service client library in ARM(Azure.ResourceManager)to get list of app service instances or the slots of a subscription

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-appservice

Where can I find the Azure App service client library in Azure Resource Manager Azure.ResourceManager to get list of app service instances or the slots of a subscription

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following steps

1. Create a service principal and assign Azure RABC role to the sp
2. Package

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager.Resources" Version="1.0.0-preview.2" />
```

3. Code

```
ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantDomain, clientId, clientSecret);
ResourcesManagementClient client = new ResourcesManagementClient(subscription, credential);
#list instance
var instances= await client.Resources.GetAsync("<group name>", "Microsoft.Web/sites", "<web name>", "instances",string.Empty, "2020-12-01");

#list slots
var slots = await client.Resources.GetAsync("<group name>", "Microsoft.Web/sites", "<web name>", "slots", string.Empty, "2020-12-01");

#list slots instance
var slotInstances= await client.Resources.GetAsync("<group name>", "Microsoft.Web/sites", "<web name>", "slots", "<slot name>/instances", "2020-12-01");
```

For more details, please refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listinstanceidentifiers

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listinstanceidentifiersslot